# Skip the "why" when I'm rejecting an audit in the Suggested Edits queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits

The frequency of the "see if you are paying attention" is quite high.

If I hit reject, I think the "why" screen should be omitted, since after all the reason does not *really* matter, does it? One of those small annoyances ...

Comment: If you're just trying to pass an audit, hit Reject and Edit, which will pass immediately with no further interaction. Otherwise... SO doesn't have enough rejections, but it has too many bad rejections. This is not an idea I can support in general.

Comment: Feel free to post the first part of your comment as an answer. As for the second part: yes, I am only talking about audits.

Comment: So you want the reject button on a audit not to ask you for a reject reason?

Comment: Correct. However, as has been noted in the answer below, "Reject and edit" is one click instead of three, so I'll use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please see the other answer. I no longer stand by this answer.**

<sub>I can't delete or edit this too much, since it has upvotes. Changing the answer will make it look like my new opinion has supporters, and it might not have.</sub>

---

**Old answer:**

> since after all the reason does not really matter

I agree!

To test the system, I just deliberately selected an obviously incorrect rejection reason to an audit.

I was hoping for a message saying something like:

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. This edit was clearly vandalizing the post, and you selected a wrong reason for rejection.

When the reason to reject an edit is not checked, there is no reason to have the system ask for it.

---

That being said: I'm not sure this is where the developers should direct their attention.

Comment: The "Reject and edit" does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has nothing to do with the reason for closing, it's a way to stop robot-reviewers (make their life harder).

Suppose you where asked for a reason every time you vote to close a question, but you don't have to select a reason when closing audits. This would make it very easy to game the system and detect audits without even looking at the question.

Simply clicking the "Close" button will reveal if the question is an audit or not. What you do with that information is up to you.

I know there are audits that show posts that shouldn't be closed, but those are rare (as far as I can tell). I just skipped through more than 100 reviews to find one, but I wasn't given a single audit where a good question was shown.

---

<sub>I know I know, it's easy to detect if a question is an audit, but there's no need to make it even easier. The point is that you should figure it out by actually reading and reviewing the question.</sub>